# How I can concatenate multiple files in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, codeigniter, ubuntu

This is my code:

```
filenames = ['DAY_1.txt', 'DAY_2.txt']
    with open('house_a.txt', 'w') as House_A:
        for fname in filenames:
             with open(fname) as copyfile:
                for line in copyfile:
                House_A.write(line)
```

My **folder** is stored in

> Downloads/Aras/House A/(DAY_1.txt, DAY_2.txt....)

I want to **concatenate** all `DAY_1.txt` up to `DAY_30.txt` in one file `House_a.txt` ?

Can someone tell me an easy method?

Comment: Can you tell us what the issue is with your current code?

Comment: Yes, please explain what is currently not working in your own implementation.

Comment: error is ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f07da07cff23> in <module>()
      1 filenames = ['DAY_1.txt','DAY_2.txt ']
----> 2 with open('/home/dhrumil/Downloads/Aras/House_A', 'w') as outfile:
      3     for fname in filenames:
      4         with open(fname) as infile:
      5             for line in infile:

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/dhrumil/Downloads/Aras/House_A'

Comment: @Dhrumil Edit your question and put that error in your question and format it properly, please.

Comment: The error is clearly telling you that `/home/dhrumil/Downloads/Aras/House_A` is a directory and *not* a file. Ensure you are passing the correct path and crafting the proper path AND filename. `os.path.join`(your_dir, filename)` <- something like that

Answer (score 0):

To help with what is probably going on in your code. You are performing a write operation, so each time you iterate through the files you are looking to grab data from, you are going to re-write the entire file each time in your loop. What you are actually looking to do is use the `'a'` (append) directive instead.

Furthermore, you are looping over the file you are reading, which is really not necessary. You can read the entire contents without the loop using the `read` or `readlines` method.

Here is an example to help illustrate.

assuming two files already exist: `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`.

Contents of `f1.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Contents of 'f2.txt`:

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

```
>>> fns = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt']
>>> fn = 'f3.txt'
>>> with open(fn, 'a') as fa:
...  for f in fns:
...   with open(f) as fr:
...    fa.write(fr.read())
...
```

contents of 'f3.txt':

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: i understand the code but if my all .txt file are stored in this directory:/home/dhrumil/Downloads/Aras/House_A how i can access this all text files

Comment: @Dhrumil You need to better explain your problem then. What is happening in your code? What error are you receiving? You need to provide all these details. Update your question to include all the important details to understand what you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
with open('House_a.txt', 'w') as out:
    for file_name in os.listdir('folder/where/files_stored'):
        with open(file_name) as file:
            out.write(file.read())
```

`os.listdir` show all files in directory.